# python pandas DataFrame - compare two identically indexed and labeled dataframes cell by cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe with exactly same indices and columns. Some of their values are different, and I want to generate a new dataframe with the same index and column but each cell indicating the result of comparison between the two dataframes.

Dataframe 1:

```
     2018    2019    2020
A     1       1       1
B     0       1       2
C     2       0       0
```

Dataframe 2:

```
     2018    2019    2020
A     1       0       0
B     0       1       1
C     1       1       1
```

Essentially, I am trying to apply the following function to each pair of cells from the two dataframe with same index and same column, and then map the result of comparison to a new dataframe at the same position:

```
def compare_two(cell_1, cell_2):
    if cell_1 == cell_2:
        return "same"
    elif cell_1 == 0 and cell_2 > 0:
        return "rise"
    elif cell_2 == 0 and cell_1 > 0:
        return "fall"
    elif cell_1 * cell_2 == 2:
        return "change"
```

The result dataframe should look like:

```
     2018    2019    2020
A    same    fall    fall
B    same    same    change
C    change  rise    rise
```

How should I achieve this?

Comment: as per your function C_2019 having result as 'rise'.. plz check and update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `numpy.select`:

```
data = np.select([df1.eq(df2), 
                  df1.eq(0) & df2.gt(0),
                  df2.eq(0) & df1.gt(0), 
                  df1.mul(df2).eq(2)],
                 ["same", "rise", "fall", "change"])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = df1.columns, index=df1.index)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
     2018  2019    2020
A    same  fall    fall
B    same  same  change
C  change  rise    rise
```

Answer (score 1):

other way you can use `np.where` with `np.logic` function to replace your function

```py
result_data = np.where(df1==df2,'Same',
              np.where(np.logical_and(df1==0 ,df2>0),"rise",
              np.where(np.logical_and(df2==0 , df1>0),"fall",
              np.where(df1*df2==2,"change",""))))

result = pd.DataFrame(result_data,index=df1.index,columns=df1.columns)
```

output

```py
    2018    2019    2020
A   Same    fall    fall
B   Same    Same    change
C   change  rise    rise
```